# Radio Buttons circle not visible within Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'd like to have radio buttons [image] within these tabs (I'm no expert at css

[image]

I tried to add this rules to css but it still does not work

```
    .custom-radio [type=radio] {

    visibility: true;
}
```

Here's the whole html and js source :

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://onlinehtmltools.com/tab-generator/skins/skin1/left.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://onlinehtmltools.com/tab-generator/skins/skin3/top.css">

<style>

    .custom-radio [type=radio] {

        visibility: true;
    }

    .tabs {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 200px; /* This part sucks */
    clear: both;
    margin: 25px 0;
    }
    .tab {
    float: left;
    }
    .tab label {
    background: #eee;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-left: -1px;
    position: relative;
    left: 1px;
    }
    .tab [type=radio] {
    display: none;
    }
    .content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 28px;
    left: 0;
    background: white;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;

    overflow: hidden;
    }
    .content > * {
    opacity: 0;

    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);

    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -moz-transform:    translateX(-100%);
    -ms-transform:     translateX(-100%);
    -o-transform:      translateX(-100%);

    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -moz-transition:    all 0.6s ease;
    -ms-transition:     all 0.6s ease;
    -o-transition:      all 0.6s ease;
    }
    [type=radio]:checked ~ label {
    background: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    z-index: 2;
    }
    [type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
    z-index: 1;
    }
    [type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content > * {
    opacity: 1;

    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform:    translateX(0);
    -ms-transform:     translateX(0);
    -o-transform:      translateX(0);
    }    
</style>

<div class="tabs_holder">
<ul>
<li><a href="#your-tab-id-1">Tab 1</a></li>
<li class="tab_selected"><a href="#your-tab-id-2">Tab 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#your-tab-id-3">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="content_holder">
<div id="your-tab-id-1">
    <div class="tabs">

    <div class="tab">
        <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
        <label for="tab-1">Tab 1.1</label>

        <div class="content">
            <p>Stuff for Tab 1.1</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab">
        <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
        <label for="tab-2">Tab 1.2</label>

        <div class="content">
            <p>Stuff for Tab 1.2</p>

            <img src="//placekitten.com/200/100">
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="tab">
        <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
        <label for="tab-3">Tab 1.3</label>

        <div class="content">
            <p>Stuff for Tab 1.3</p>

            <img src="//placedog.com/200/100">
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>  
<div id="your-tab-id-3">

    <div class="tabs">

    <div class="tab">
        <input type="radio" id="tab-4" name="tab-group-2" checked>
        <label for="tab-4">Tab 3.1</label>

        <div class="content">
            <p>
                    <form name="form_1">

                    <input type="radio" name ="radio_1" class="custom-radio" onClick="offButton();">Light off

                    <input type="radio" name ="radio_2" class="custom-radio" onClick="onButton();" checked>Light on

                    </form>                   
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab">
        <input type="radio" id="tab-5" name="tab-group-2">
        <label for="tab-5">Tab 3.2</label>

        <div class="content">
            <p>Stuff for Tab 3.2</p>

            <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/100">
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="tab">
        <input type="radio" id="tab-6" name="tab-group-2">
        <label for="tab-6">Tab 3.2</label>

        <div class="content">
            You made it this far?!
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>    
</div><!-- /.content_holder -->
</div><!-- /.tabs_holder -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://onlinehtmltools.com/tab-generator/skinable_tabs.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.tabs_holder').skinableTabs({
    effect: 'basic_display',
    skin: 'skin1',
    position: 'left'
});
</script>


</html>
```

Comment: .custom-radio [type=radio] {

        visibility: visible;
    } true is not a correct  value for visibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.tab [type=radio] {
display: none;
}
```

Needs to be removed, but then the radio buttons will show for the tabs, so you'll need to make sure they are hidden, something like the following should work:

```
.tab [type=radio] {
display: none;
}

.tab form [type=radio] {
display: inline-block;
}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

remove the following `css` from your code.

```
  .tab [type=radio] {
      display: none;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using css like this

```
 .tab [type=radio] {
   display: none;
 }
```

so you have to use this for it display again

```
 .tab [type=radio] {
   display: block;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with

```
.tab [type=radio] {
display: none;
}
```

Add specific CSS to display those Radio Buttons like this, this will select only those Radio Buttons

```
.custom-radio [type=radio] {
display:block;
}
```

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2gufh7fp/1/)